# Raycasting with layer masks

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting, physics-engine

I have recently begun learning RayCasting in Unity for a game that I'm making, but I am encountering problems when trying to filter my 2 Dimensional RayCast with a layer mask.

I am trying to use a raycast to determine whether or not there is a wall object (Which is basically a 2D square prefab with a box collider) in the path of the ray.

I have placed all the wall objects on user layer 8 (called "Walls"), and hope to use a layer mask that only allows the ray to make contact with objects on the Walls layer in order to avoid the ray colliding with any other objects.

The RayCast I am using starts within another object that is not on the Walls layer; without the LayerMask the ray will make contact with that object instantly, and return that object instead.

Here is the code where I am trying to use a RayCast with a LayerMask filter

```
print("testing for collisions");
relitivePos = new Vector2(turns[k+1].x-turns[k].x,turns[k+1].y-turns[k].y);
relitivePos = new Vector2(Mathf.Round(relitivePos.x), Mathf.Round(relitivePos.y));
int layerMask = (1 << 8);
//layerMask = ~layerMask;
RaycastHit2D hitInfo = Physics2D.Raycast(turns[k], relitivePos, (relitivePos.y.Equals(1) ? turns[k + 1].y - turns[k].y : turns[k + 1].x - turns[k].x), layerMask);
UnityEngine.Debug.DrawLine(turns[k], turns[k + 1], Color.blue, 100f);
print("hit? " + (hitInfo.collider != null? "true":"false"));
if (hitInfo.collider != null)
{
    print("gameobject" + hitInfo.collider.gameObject);
    print("collider name " + hitInfo.collider.name);
}
```

I have tried bit shifting an int by the layer number in order to create a LayerMask, as well as using `LayerMask.GetMask("Walls");` In both of these cases the RayCast does not appear to hit anything (`prints: "hit? false"`). When removing the LayerMask it will print the object that the LayerMask initially starts in (`prints:"collider name door"`).

### I don't understand why my RayCast does not detect objects on a specific layer when using a LayerMask?

Update:

- I have since tried making a 'public LayerMask wallLayerMask;', and
  feeding the Walls layer through the unity interface, but this did not
  seem to yield any different results than just using
  'LayerMask.GetMask("Walls");'
- Going off of what Drako18s said, I think that '1<<8' is the right way to 
  create the layer mask (rather than 'LayerMask.GetMask("Walls");'. If I 
  understand it 
  right, I could in theory do '1 << LayerMask.GetMask("Walls");' and that would 
  be the same thing as '1 << 8'
- Minimal reproducible example

  int layerMask = 1<<8;
  RaycastHit2D hitInfo = Physics2D.Raycast(Vector2.zero, Vector2.up, 10, layerMask);
  print("hit? " + (hitInfo.collider != null? "true":"false"));
      if (hitInfo.collider != null)
      {
          print("gameobject" + hitInfo.collider.gameObject);
          print("collider name " + hitInfo.collider.name);
      }

Comment: There is too much contextual code to follow in your example. Please try and make a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: What I do to avoid this LayerMask annoyance, is have a [SerializedField] private LayerMask layerMask; and assign it with the editor.

Comment: Can you share the line of code that works if you remove the layermask

Comment: `1<<8` (`256`) only hits layer #8. `LayerMask.NameToLayer("Name of Layer 8")` returns `8`, not `256`. The raycast function uses a bitmask, and the LayerMask class is a poor name decision, as it is not actually a *mask* but just a set of handy methods to make magic numbers like `1<<8` go away.

Comment: If this is a monobehaviour, you could simply add the layermask as a public property, and select the layers you want the raycast to hit or ignore. i think the problem in your code is that it's also ignoring layer 8. not sure though

Comment: @SamuelG I've updated the post with a minimal reproducible example: int